# Spring Data findAllById not work properly

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE lib.
When I'd like to use ***JpaRepository.findAllById***(Iterable ids)
with 2 ids debug show me error

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException: 
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
Error Code: 1241
Call: SELECT ID, CONFIGURATION, IMPORT_ID, NAME, STATE FROM TB_MARKET WHERE (ID IN ((?,?)))
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=MarketEntity sql="SELECT ID, CONFIGURATION, IMPORT_ID, NAME, STATE FROM TB_MARKET WHERE (ID IN (?))")
```

Error code 1241 for MySQL say that to much ( )

Comment: Seems like this is still a bug... https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349477

Comment: As a workaround also described in this bug report you can use JPQL or Criteria API.

Answer (score 1):

First Id try updating to the latest Spring data jpa library which is 2.1.1.RELEASE

for Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are unable to update the libraries it might be better to roll your own query in your repository if this is a known issue in the version you're using:

In your repository in question add:

```
List<Entity> findByIdIn(Set<Integer> ids);
```

Having the id's as a set will prevent duplicate id's from being in the final query when it gets translated to the sql statement.